# Annoying KMPlayer key-frame positioning/seeking in video playback

Tags: audio, video, kmplayer

I've been using **KMPlayer** for about a decade. In older versions the user could jump to the exact positions of time in both audio and video files, but since a certain version, if the user wants to jump to an exact time of the video (either by pressing keyboard shortcuts--left and right arrow keys-- or by clicking on the seekbar itself) each time the video jumps to an uncertain positions before or after that particular time. And it does not matter how precisely they click, making **KMPlayer** absolutely useless for reviewing videos.
It's worth mentioning that unlike video playback, audio files still work perfectly and any click on the audios jumps to the exact position.

I tried finding any options if/any about key-frames in `Options` > menu `Play` and `Playback` sections but did not find anything special.

P.S. there is the same story about the well-known Android application **MX-Player**. It also seeks audios time perfectly, but on videos it behaves unkindly! In case of **MX-Player** I also found an option in the path: `Settings` > `Player` > `Fast Seeking` and I unchecked it, but nothing changed.

Any help on "how to disable this annoying feature" about either applications would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were those video files always using the same codec as you're using today? Some codecs indeed don't support exact seeking to all positions. (Something I-frames something.)

Comment: My video files are all in this format with slightly different bitrates
Video: MPEG4 Video (H264) 1280x720 15fps 178kbps [V: Telestream, LLC Telestream Media Framework - Release Multiscreen 2018.136.243632 [eng] (h264 main L3.1, yuv420p, 1280x720, 178 kb/s)]
Audio: AAC 48000Hz stereo 160kbps [A: Telestream, LLC Telestream Media Framework - Release Multiscreen 2018.136.243632 (aac lc, 48000 Hz, stereo, 160 kb/s)]
Also, I don't think it's a Codec issue, since **Windows Media Player** plays them with exact time positioning.

Answer (score 0):

### in the latest version, which is  KMPlayer (64-bit)

Build information:
Version:            2023.4.26.13
Compiler:           MSVC 2015 Update 3
Build date:         Apr 26 2023 12:05:41
you can go to options->tweaks->untick the box for fast seek and thats it.